# How to install PATCH UPDATE 1533 5344

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, upgrade, security, patches

I paid someone that developed the my website for me. He provided me the magento login info to access my website. Currently, the person cannot be reached and I need to know how to install 3 patches to my website. My websited was hosted via JustHost and I will like to know how to install these security patches. can somebody please guide me on how to do this. I use apple computer, I have access to JUSthost, cpanel, ftp, etc. I need to know what to do please. I don't have any coding or programming knowledge. So please, i will appreciate it if the explanation is easy.

A million thanks :)

Comment: The easiest thing to do is ask your hosting provider to install them.

Comment: Please, any more details on how to ask them to install the patches?

Comment: Yes. Download the patches from the official Magento site and tell the support guy you talk to that the patches should be executed like "sh patchname.sh" in the root folder of your Magento installation.

Comment: Just as a friendly note, if you haven't installed SUPEE-5344 by now, and your site is available to the public, then your site has most likely already been compromised. If it has been compromised, you'll need a skilled developer to clean things up.

Comment: what do you suggest I do. does that mean that after installing these patches, it will do little or not good at all?

Comment: Applying patches after a compromise is like shutting the barn door **and** gate after the horses have escaped into the next county. Especially on 5344.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the Magento Article "How to apply patches"

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html

In the section: **How to Apply a Magento Patch** you will see the proper instructions for installing your patch.

1. Transfer the patch .sh file to your Magento installation root
   directory.
2. Enter the following command as a user with sufficient privileges to
   write to Magento files (typically, the web server user or root):

   sh patch-file-name.sh

A message such as the following displays to confirm the patch installed successfully:

```
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.
```

3. To reapply ownership to the files changed by the patch:

   a. Find the web server user: ps -o "user group command" -C httpd,apache2
   The value in the USER column is the web server user name.
   Typically, the Apache web server user on CentOS is apache and the Apache web server user on Ubuntu is www-data.

   b. As a user with root privileges, enter the following command from the Magento installation directory:

   chown -R web-server-user-name .